# SD card not showing up under /dev

Tags: udev, hardware, sd-card, thinkpad, peripherals

I'm trying to mount a 2gb Kingston SD card on a Lenovo ThinkPad t420s running Arch Gnu/Linux with kernel version 5.2.6. It has a removable SD card reader connected with an ExpressCard slot. I've previously found this reader to be fully functional, and the SD card worked fine in a camera.

When I insert the SD card into the reader it is not visible when I run `lsblk` or look under `/dev` with `ls`. In the past when I've had this problem with the SD reader or my (currently functional) USB ports, a reboot fixed it.

I would like to figure out a solution that does not require me to reboot my machine. Is it possible to re-detect hardware on the fly? Something with `udev` perhaps?

I ran `dmesg` before and after inserting the card, and a `diff` of the outputs yielded this:

```
> [55367.604387] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
> [55367.604769] sdhci-pci 0000:05:00.0: Will use DMA mode even though HW doesn't fully claim to support it.
> [55367.867535] mmc0: new high speed SD card at address 0002
```

Comment: What does `dmesg` say when you insert the card?

Comment: Could you try with a USB-connected SD card reader to rule out problems with ExpressCard?

Comment: Some cameras format the cards in ways that Linux can't mount, thus it won't show up.

Comment: @vonbrand Would a foreign filesystem prevent the device from showing up in `/dev`? I don't see why it would.

Comment: This behaviour was reported as a bug on a wide range of hardware and kernel versions, see for example https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810416 There is also an open discussion on kernel.org: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93201